# Liquidsoap does not recognise alsa

Tags: alsa, liquidsoap

I want to setup an internet radio using Liquidsoap and Icecast 2.

I've installed Liquidsoap using Opam Package Manager as described in [Liquidsoap Install Manual](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.2/install.html#install-using-opam). I am able to stream a file running the following code:

```
output.icecast(%vorbis,
mount = "radio",
host = "MYSERVER", port = 8000,
password = "MYPASSWORD",
mksafe(single("SONG.mp3")))
```

with the use of `~/.opam/4.08.0/bin/liquidsoap radio.liq`.

However, when I am trying to run `output.alsa(input.alsa())` Liquidsoap returns `Error 4: Undefined variable output.alsa`.

I've checked if my alsa is running with `services --status-all`, tried to record something with `arecord` and then play it with `aplay` and looks like ALSA is working just fine. I am wondering if I may lack some specific packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I've checked if ALSA has some OPAM package. And it looks like it does.

Running `opam install alsa` helped, I don't know why this information is not on the official Liquidsoap webpage.

I am leaving it here, so it may help somebody else.